# How to add "rel=nofollow" for links in latest version of Wordpress?

Tags: block-editor, visual-editor

In earlier versions of Wordpress, when editing a link, there are three options:

- Open in new tab
- Search engines should ignore this link (mark as nofollow)Learn more
  about marking a link as nofollow or sponsored.(Opens in a new browser
  tab)
- This is a sponsored link or advert (mark as sponsored)

In latest version, there is only one option:

- Open in new tab

I know I can edit the link as HTML and add the "rel=nofollow" but I don't think it is the right way to do it. How to add the "rel=nofollow" now?

I'm actually curious about the philosophy behind this. As you know, the new Wordpress Gutenberg editor removes some commonly used functionalities of the classic editor making common tasks such as changing the font/color of text difficult. Now, new Wordpress version keeps removing old features of old versions. Why?

Comment: are you asking how to add the nofollow or are you asking why features get removed or not added? We have a 1 question per question policy and they must remain grounded in facts as this isn't a discussion board, keeping a tight focus will get you better answers and more attention

Comment: note that this was never added to the block editor, it didn't get removed, and there's a lengthy issue already raised on the github repo about this with people discussing it and designs etc https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/23011

Comment: it also reveals that the options in your bullet points are not and never have been provided by the editor, but are actually 3rd party plugin features, most likely Yoast SEO